# Removing Extension From Asp.Net Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Does anybody know how to remove extension from asp pages. I am using simple web forms.

I have a page

```
www.example.com/offers.aspx?id=10
```

what i want is that the url should be shown as

```
www.example.com/offers?id=10
```

is there any way to do this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by **URL Rewriting**

check these links :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: i want to do this in asp.net not in php.

Comment: Yes , it is for ASP.NET .. you can check the examples here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use seo friendly url extension for this. I think easy and best way.
Here is the article for it. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/using-friendly-urls-in-asp.net-web-forms.htm
[image]

Comment: thanks. i did it by using Routing concept.
i added the System.Web.Routing reference in my project. and then i added Global.asax file and in application_start module i wrote
  
**`RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("", "example", "~/example.aspx");`**